# compare 2d array against another 2d array by checking arrays with same elements

Tags: javascript, typescript

Have a 2d array (Arr1) and not able to get a check/compare against another 2d array (Arr2) to count arrays what match with exact elements.
**for example:**

```
const arr1: string[][] = [
  ["R", "P"],
  ["R", "S"],
  ["S", "P"],
];
const checkAgainst: string[][] = [
  ["R", "S"],
  ["P", "R"],
  ["S", "P"],
];

function check(arr1: string[][]) {
  arr1.map((a, index, arr) => {
    let result = arr[0].filter((o1) =>
      checkAgainst.some((o2) => o1.id === o2.id)
    );
  });
}
console.log(check(arr1));
```

Return should be `true, false, true` or just `1, 0, 1`, so in the end can count amount of `true or 1`, expected outcome: `true===2`

Any good way to do that **without** using for loops?

Comment: Add sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Posted with example, somehow missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function haveSameValues(arr1: string[], arr2: string[]): boolean {
  if (arr1.length === 0 || arr1.length != arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function countMatches(matrix1: string[][], matrix2: string[][]): number {
  let count = 0;

  for (const arr1 of matrix1) {
    for (const arr2 of matrix2) {
      if (haveSameValues(arr1, arr2) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }

  return count;
}

const arr1: string[][] = [
  ["R", "P"],
  ["R", "S"],
  ["S", "P"],
];
const checkAgainst: string[][] = [
  ["R", "S"],
  ["P", "R"],
  ["S", "P"],
];

console.log(countMatches(arr1, checkAgainst));
```